# one to many join filter condition

Tags: sql

I have these tables

##### TableA

| id | nameId | locationId | addressId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | bob | ny | abc |
| 200 | bean | uk | zx |

##### TableB

| type | Ids |
| --- | --- |
| name | bob |
| location | ny |
| address | abc |
| name | bean |
| location | uk |

##### Expected output

| id | nameId | locationId | addressId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | bob | ny | abc |

I need the only output from tableA, where all three columns (`nameId, locationId, addressId`) are a match with tableB.

In the expected output, as you can see, `nameId` can only look into `type` column (`tableB`) where value is `name` and filter out only if its corresponding `Id` matches.

Since I'm doing this in spark, there I'm doing join 3 times, and it is increasing the volume of data in memory, because every join's output creates a dataset which is kept in memory.

We can alter `tableB` too if needed, if in case it helps for better approach. As of now, I thought of this way only. I've created `tableB` by doing union of diff `types` and corresponding `Ids`

I'm looking for a way, where I could achieve this in single join, so that unnecessary data could be avoided in memory. I think, if I get any idea of doing it with single join SQL query that can be implemented in spark too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could Pivot TableB first and perform then the join with TableA.

```sql
-- Pivoting tableB first
WITH pivoted_tableB AS (
  SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'name' THEN Ids ELSE NULL END) AS nameId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'location' THEN Ids ELSE NULL END) AS locationId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'address' THEN Ids ELSE NULL END) AS addressId
  FROM tableB
  GROUP BY 1
),
-- Joining tableA with the pivoted tableB
filtered_tableA AS (
  SELECT A.*
  FROM tableA A
  INNER JOIN pivoted_tableB B ON A.nameId = B.nameId AND A.locationId = B.locationId AND A.addressId = B.addressId
)
-- Select the output
SELECT * FROM filtered_tableA;
```

Comment: pivoting is not possible, because while doing inion different types of datasets (name, location, address) can have different number of records